# Updating cumulative sum by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

hi guys i need help!

i've a table sql like this:

```
id | in | out
1  | 32 | 23
2  | 4  | 0
3  | 10 | 3
```

i need a result like this:

```
id | in | out| cumulative
1  | 32 | 23 | 9
2  | 4  | 0  | 13
3  | 10 | 3  | 20
```

is possible to do in sql ?? how?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use a subquery like this:

```
select id,
      [in],
      [out],
      (SELECT ABS(SUM([out] - [in])) 
        from ##temp as c2 where id <= c1.id) as cumulative
from ##temp as c1
```

Where **##temp** is your table

Comment: very beautiful & KISS